# Using a random color for an SVG being exported as a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have three SVGs that I'm using as React components. The three SVGs are currently being saved as JavaScript files. They are being used like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PictureA from '../components/SVGs/PictureA.js'
import PictureB from '../components/SVGs/PictureB.js'
import PictureC from '../components/SVGs/PictureC.js'


const IndexPage = () => (
  <div className="mainArea">
    <PictureB />
    <PictureA />
    <PictureC />
  </div>
)

export default IndexPage
```

The above part works fine. Within, for example, PictureA.js, I would like to have something like this happen:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function PictureA(props) {
  return (
      <svg
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       svg width = "12rem"
       height = "auto"
       version = "1.1"
       viewBox = "-10 -110 100 250"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice">
        <g transform="translate(-2.202509394435669,-16.15250659108221)"
    fill = "FILL THIS WITH A RANDOM COLOR"
    fill-opacity = "0.90087" >
    <path
       d="very long path" />
      </g>
    </svg>
);
}
```

I have an array of pre-selected colors, and it's no problem to select from that array. The problem I'm having is in inserting a color once selected into:

```
fill = "FILL THIS WITH A RANDOM COLOR"
```

I've been trying to save the randomly selected color as a variable and populate it directly inside the  tag. After doing some research, I get the feeling that's the wrong approach. But if there is a way to make that work, that would be optimal. If that isn't the right approach, I would still really appreciate any help making the randomization work within the PictureA.js file. It would be best to have the SVGs self-contained, if that's possible.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing a generated color as a `prop`?

```
fill = { props.color }
```

And then call it as

```
<PictureA color={ chooseRandomColor() } />
```

**[EDIT]** If you want this to be self-contained, you can also just inline the call to the random color generator:

```
  return (
      <svg
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       svg width = "12rem"
       height = "auto"
       version = "1.1"
       viewBox = "-10 -110 100 250"
       preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax slice">
        <g transform="translate(-2.202509394435669,-16.15250659108221)"
        fill = { chooseRandomColor() }
        fill-opacity = "0.90087" >
        <path ... />
    )
}
```

You can inline JavaScript by surrounding it with `{ }` tags in React JSX templates. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) in the react docs for an example.

Comment: Thanks! It's not quite as self-contained as I was hoping, but it works and it's time to move on!

Comment: Edited to reflect a more self-contained strategy. Good luck!

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much!